# How to create a Windows Phone 8 app package?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have developed one Windows Phone 8 app using VS12. I am currently testing it on emulator. I want to forward this project for further testing. So, my question is how to create a package of same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package is in your project, path like this: `ProjectName\Bin\Debug(or Release)\yourAppName.xap`, you can get the xap file in this path.

Comment: You can also make use of the Beta program under dev.windowsphone.com which allows you to submit a xap and get it run through the submission process (albeit a quick version).  Its then available usually within hours and can be available to 100 beta testers, which is very handy.

Comment: Can you help me with where can i get this path. like i have a source code, i'm able to run it and see output in emulator, but i'm unable to see .xap file. My requirement is to install .xap file in emulator

Comment: You can deploy xap file using XapDeploy.exe from your PC to emulator. The xap file path is ProjectName\Bin\Debug(or Release)\yourAppName.xap.

Comment: How do I sign this .xap file?

Answer (score 0):

In case we talk about Windows Phone 8.1 (not 8.0) the way to go is different. Open your solution in Visual Studio, then click the project with your Windows Phone code.

**Important:** you must have the project as "blue-selected", i.e. focused. If your Solution Explorer widget lost the focus and the project is "gray-selected", nothing to appear in the menu as enabled item.

Then, having the project selected and focused, immediately go to main menu: Project -> Store -> Create App Packages